# Structured streaming debugging input

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

Is there a way for me to print out the incoming data? For e.g. I have a readStream on a folder looking for JSON files, however there seems to be an issue as I am seeing 'nulls' in the aggregation output.

```scala
val schema = StructType(
      StructField("id", LongType, false) ::
      StructField("sid", IntegerType, true) ::
      StructField("data", ArrayType(IntegerType, false), true) :: Nil)

val lines = spark.
      readStream.
      schema(schema).
      json("in/*.json")

val top1 = lines.groupBy("id").count()

val query = top1.writeStream
      .outputMode("complete")
      .format("console")
      .option("truncate", "false")
      .start()
```

Comment: Why don't you `lines.writeStream.format("console")` then?

Answer (score 1):

To print the data you can add queryName in the write stream, by using that queryName you can print.

In your Example

```
val query = top1.writeStream
      .outputMode("complete")
      .queryName("xyz")
      .format("console")
      .option("truncate", "false")
      .start()
```

run this and you can display data by using SQL query

```
%sql select * from xyz
```

or you can Create Dataframe

```
val df = spark.sql("select * from xyz")
```

Comment: How to do a show of this val df = spark.sql("select * from xyz")? You mean val df = spark.sql("select count(*) from xyz")?